# Using jQuery in Tampermonkey

Tags: jquery, tampermonkey

I'm using Chrome 27.0.1453.116 m and have enabled "Experimental Javascript", however I'm unable to get jQuery to run on Tampermonkey.

I have tried:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       My Fancy New Userscript
// @require    http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

var $ = unsafeWindow.jQuery;
var jQuery = unsafeWindow.jQuery;
```

However, I get an error on the line `var $ = unsafeWindow.jQuery;` highlighting `unsafeWindow` saying unsafeWindow was used before it was defined. How to fix this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

EDIT: Since Greasemonkey 2.0 you do not (and cannot) use `unsafeWindow.jQuery` for getting the host page's instance of jQuery. You just use `window.jQuery`, and `// @grant none` (or `@grant` whatever other special APIs you need for non-jQuery things).

Sources:
https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues/1952
http://www.greasespot.net/2014/06/greasemonkey-20-release.html

[Tampermonkey currently (Feb 2015) seems to work similarly by default settings.](https://web.archive.org/web/20150312163515/https://www.tampermonkey.net/faq.php#Q404) (archived on 2015-03-12 from http://tampermonkey.net/faq.php#Q404)

---

old outdated answer below:

> Add a directive `// @grant unsafeWindow`.  Also, if you are getting
> your jQuery reference from the host window object, you won't need the
> `@require` line.

Comment: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
when i try $.get("interface.php?func=get_unit_info", function(data){
    opslag = data
});