# Tampermonkey clicking a button by class

Tags: function, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

So i have a school issue where i need to access a site but this site requires me to go through around 4 portals to get there and am hoping to just write a quick script to do this for me. Problem comes where the site is very sloppy and are written with names being the same on certian buttons so I would like to click the buttons based on class

the classes are readit2, readit23, readit239, and readit2394

```
 $(function(){
        document.getElementByClassName(readit2).click();
       });
```

the above code i thought would click it as soon as it loads the first page but does not. any help would be great

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       dumb spider web
// @namespace  ===============
// @version    0.1
// @description  gets me through this dumb stuff
// @match      ===============
// @copyright  2012+, You
// @require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js
// ==/UserScript==
```

edit ^ added the header stuff

more edits:

it works through the console now but through tamper monkey OR grease monkey I can not get it to actually preform the action.

```
$(function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName("readit2")[0].click();
});
```

Works through console but does not run when script is started.

Comment: How are you trying to run it?  User-script or just trying it in the console?

Comment: I am trying to run it through the "tampermonkey" built in chrome app

Comment: You posted that it the title, sorry for overlooking that.  Have you included the `@require` for jquery?  It may be helpful if you post the  header portion (just remove the url for your site, if you want to retain that privacy).  I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255303/using-jquery-in-tampermonkey) is an example of it working.

Comment: edited the original post with what I had, I also tried the link you sent with the require and replaced mine with that and no change.

Comment: still kinda looking for help with this issue, OP edited again

Comment: So, that is what I was getting at with taking your issue one step at a time.  Now that you know the console works, the issue appears to be with your invokation.  IIRC userscripts do not always get run at the same time, and waiting for the document ready may get called once, but not set an event that is called.  One option would be to do something like [this](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/domready.shtml).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I started looking at all the wrong things, your original code:

```
$(function(){
    document.getElementByClassName(readit2).click();
});
```

The issue with this is that the call should be `getElementsByClassName` (plural "Elements"), since class is usually a shared property.  That also returns an array, so if you are positive that there is only 1 ever:

```
$(function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName("readit2")[0].click();
});
```

If not, I'd suggest getting the text and verifying that it contains something that you expect.

Edit: Added quotes.

Comment: i've tried this code without it working as well, i looked over the page once more and this is the only thing using class "readit2" it is a button.

<input onclick="AJAX(&quot;DoAction-7&amp;anti=random;, &quot;read&quot;);" type="button" value="read" class="readit2" style="width: auto;">

the problem is that there are other buttons that have exact code just with different classes

Comment: @user3699068 - Go through 1 step at a time, try running the `document.getElementsByClassName(readit2)[0].click();` in the chrome console.  If it works, then the issue is probably how tampermonkey runs the script.

Comment: its saying that Reference Error: readit2 is not defined
message: "readit2 is not defined"
even though it is, do I have to specify where its looking or what Div its located in? not sure how to do that if it is needed =/

Comment: I thought you had defined a var "readit2".  Just quote it, since it is a string literal.

Comment: ah gotchyah, EDIT< works when i paste it into the console now but does not work when enabling it in tampermonkey
$(function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName("readit2")[0].click();
});
[
(the page that the link is located loads here)

Comment: I'm confused, it did work or did not when you ran it manually? (Only the `document.getEl...` piece)

Comment: it did work when i did it manually yes, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to access some nodes that still don't exist. Add this to your script:

```
// @run-at  document-end
```

Then you make sure that all nodes are loaded and printed.
Another bypass would be this:

```
$(document).ready(
    //your script
);
```

Comment: What is the JavaScript of this? Obviously this is some hybrid language. Thx