# How do I detect this text in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

```
<b id="flash">Rated Image</b>
```

I want to be able to detect if that text is on screen with Tampermonkey then if detected close the tab.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use jquery within tampermonkey.

[Here's a link on how to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255303/using-jquery-in-tampermonkey)

Then you can just do

```
if ($("#flash").text == "Rated Image") {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for jQuery, plain JS works:

```js
if (document.querySelector('b #flash').innerText === 'Rated Image') {
  window.close();
}
```